# Preg match all after closing img

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having a small issue with wordpress; what i want to achieve is move my first image on a blog post to the top of the div, and the content somewhere else. My current script looks like this:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);

foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
$author = get_the_author(); 

echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 blog" ><div class="inner">';

preg_match_all("/(<img [^>]*>)/",$recent["post_content"],$img,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    echo $img[1][0];    

echo '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . $recent["post_title"].'</a></h3> ';

echo '<h6>' . $author . '</h6>';

preg_match_all("/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/s",$recent["post_content"],$content,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo '<p>';
    echo $content[1][0];
echo '</p>';    

 echo '</div>';
echo '</div>;
}
```

Instead i would like to use one preg_match_all, 1st array would select my whole first img tag  and the 2nd array would select all the text after that. How can i achieve this result?

My current output from $recent["post_content"] is :

```
   <img src="">
   <p>my content</p>
```

What my desired output would be is:

```
 <img src="">
  $title
  $author
<p>my content</p>
```

Kind regards.

Comment: Can you post your input and desired output? Moving "the content somewhere else" is a little vague... do you just want to swap the image and the first `<p>` around?

Comment: Correct, my output looks like <img src=""><p>my content here</p>, what i would want to achieve is: <img src=""> $title $author <p>my content here</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'd do it: construct the post, and then use `preg_replace` to pull out the image and put it at the start of the post.

```
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    $author = get_the_author(); 
    echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 blog" ><div class="inner">';

    #construct the post
    $post = '<h3><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) 
    . '">' . $recent["post_title"].'</a></h3>'
    .'<h6>' . $author . '</h6>';
    . $recent["post_content"];

    # run the replacement:
    echo preg_replace("#(.*?)(<img[^>]+>)#s", "$2$1", $post);

    echo '</div></div>';
}
```

The regex looks for the first `img` tag, takes it and switches its position with whatever came before it.

Example: set `$post` to

```
$post = '<h3><a href="my link">title</a></h3>
<h6>author</h6><p>my content here</p>
<p>my content here</p>
<p>my content here</p>
<p>my content here</p>
<img src="img_dir/img.jpg" />
<p>my content here</p>
<p>my content here</p>';
```

Output:

```
<img src="img_dir/img.jpg" /><h3><a href="my link">title</a></h3>
<h6>author</h6><p>my content here</p>
<p>my content here</p>
<p>my content here</p>
<p>my content here</p>

<p>my content here</p>
<p>my content here</p>
```